# how to return file name , webflux file upload

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

the example is https://www.vinsguru.com/spring-webflux-file-upload/

```
@PostMapping("file/multi")
public Mono<Void> upload(@RequestPart("files") Flux<FilePart> partFlux){
    return  partFlux
                .doOnNext(fp -> System.out.println(fp.filename()))
                .flatMap(fp -> fp.transferTo(basePath.resolve(fp.filename())))
                .then();
}
```

but i want to return to upload file name

............................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.then(Mono.just(fileName))` or `.thenReturn(fileName)` to continue the flow and return file name.

```
@PostMapping("file/multi")
public Mono<String> upload(@RequestPart("files") Flux<FilePart> partFlux){
        return  partFlux
                .flatMap(fp -> {
                    var fileName = basePath.resolve(fp.filename());
                    return fp.transferTo(fileName)
                            .thenReturn(fileName);
                });
    }
```